# php/sql query is returning the wrong response

Tags: php, mysql

ok so i am running a reset password script, its supposed to replace the password with the sha1 hashed version of `password01` if successful it should return the success message if not then the failed message, but its returning the failure message weather it works  or not which it always does! any ideas? i have inserted the code below:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$host= $_SESSION["dbhost"]; 
$username= $_SESSION["dbuser"]; 
$password= $_SESSION["dbpass"]; 
$db_name= $_SESSION["dbname"];
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$userid = $_POST['id'];
$password = 'password01';    
$hashpass = sha1($password);

//$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$userid'");
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$hashpass' where id='$userid'"); 

if (mysql_query($sql)) {
echo "<ul id='breadcrumbs-one'>";
echo "<li><a href=''>Users</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='' class='current'>Reset</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "<div class='tn-box tn-box-color-3 mcenterlow'>";
echo "<p>The Opperation was Sucessful!<br><a href='?users'>Add Another?</a></p>";
echo "<div class='tn-progress'></div>";
echo "</div>";
}
else {
echo "<ul id='breadcrumbs-one'>";
echo "<li><a href=''>Users</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='' class='current'>Reset</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "<div class='tn-box tn-box-color-1 mcenterlow'>";
echo "<p>The Opperation was Not Sucessful!<br><a href='?users'>Try Again?</a></p>";
echo "<div class='tn-progress'></div>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Side note: it is usually considered a bad practice to mix application logic with presentation code.

Comment: Call `mysql_error()` in your `else {}` case to see why it failed.  Note that this is vulnerable to SQL injection. At a minimum, call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$userid`.

Comment: Apart from the sql injection, any user can change the password of any other user. You should store the user ID in the session after a successful login. Unless only the administrator can run this script of course...

Comment: You should be using PHP's crypt (blowfish) functionality for passwords, unsalted sha1's are a very bad idea.

Comment: yeah im aware of the injection attack vulnerability, i am writing this as part of a practice program for myself locally, i know the basics of php, but im really trying to expand my knowledge. appreciate the input tho, and the program code is because this is called by my mvc code so the code is run within a template wrapper kind of thing. kinda a merge of several practice projects.

@jeroen, only the admin can run this, it comes from a user list with a reset button that submits the form with the userid.

Comment: @mmattax will definately look into that! thanks for the tip!

Comment: @mmattax thanks for the tip with crypt! i have switched everything over in my code to use it instead of unsalted sha1! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the comments below your question, the reason your `if` is failing, is that you are using `mysql_query` on the result of another call to `mysql_query`.

To solve that, you should change your condition to:

```
if ($sql) {
```

(for an `UPDATE` query, `mysql_query` return `true` on success and `false` on failure)

And you should really switch to PDO (or mysqli) with prepared statements and bound variables to get rid of the sql injection problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is calling mysql_query() twice, once with the actual SQL string, and again with the returned result value from the first call!  Hence, the second call which is checked by the "if" always fails; it's not valid SQL.

I think you want to say something like

```
$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$hashpass' where id='$userid'";

if (mysql_query($sql)) {
    // etc.
```

Comment: yup that was the ide! looked over it too many times and just missed the error! haha! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `$sql` equal to the result of `mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$hashpass' where id='$userid'");`. On an UPDATE statement, `mysql_query` returns a boolean. You are THEN called `mysql_quert($sql)` in the `if` statement. This is logically incorrect, as you are checked the result of `mysql_query(<bool>);` because $sql is the RESULT of a query.

Either:

```
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$hashpass' where id='$userid'"); 

if ($sql) {
```

or

```
$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$hashpass' where id='$userid'"; 

if (mysql_query($sql)) {
```

Matt